# Difference between \declaretheorem and \newtheorem

Tags: theorems, newtheorem

What are the differences between `\declaretheorem` and `\newtheorem`? In what situation should one of them be preferred over the other?

Comment: In the base latex release, `\newtheorem` is defined, and `\declaretheorem` is not. If you have loaded a package that you have not specified that defines `\declaretheorem` presumably the package documentation will say what it does,

Comment: A package that defines `\declaretheorem` is [`thmtools`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/thmtools/thmtools.pdf), the command as defined in this package has a lot of options for numbering/counters, title style, code hooks, etc. Many of these options are extending the base LaTeX `\newtheorem` and/or the `\newtheorem` command from [`amsthm`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf).